# Utm Parameter killing our pagination

Tags: javascript, regex, wordpress

We run a WP site and currently we have a script in our footer that passes along a UTM parameter.

```
var querystring = '?utm_source=[utm_source]&utm_medium=[utm_medium]&utm_campaign=[utm_campaign]&cb=[cb]';

var UTm = '[utm_source]';

if(UTm != null && UTm !=''){
jQuery('a:not(".page-submenu li a")').each(function() {
    var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');

    if (href) {
        href += (href.match(/\?/) ? '&' : '') + querystring;


        jQuery(this).attr('href', href);
    }
});
}
```

unfortunately this kill the pagination of our blog such that the url between pages goes from 
homesite.com/blog/page/3

to

homesite/blog/?`utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blogpost+%5D%5D&cb#038;utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blogpost+%5D%5D&cbpage/33/

this throws a  Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

At this point I'm pretty open to suggestions on how to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your pagination is generating its `href`s from `location.href` and just adding `page/3` to the end, that would explain the `homesite/blog/?[querystring]page/3`

The following code removes everything after the `?` in the `href` of each anchor before re-adding the `page/[num]/` and `querystring`:

```
$('a:not(".page-submenu li a")').each(function() {
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if (href) {
        var base = href.split('?')[0];
        base += href.match(/page\/\d/g)[0];
        $(this).attr('href', base + querystring);
    }
});
```

Comment: this pretty much helped me figure out what went wrong Thank you so much.